# Save screenId for onCreate

Tags: android, orientation, bundle

I have a class which reads an XML file to create several screens in a Horizontal Page flipper.
However, the view content can be different when changing from portrait to landscape or back.

I'd like to save the current selected page so whenever I swap my screen it uses that value again to build up the new orientation screen.

I use a HorizontalPager class which can retrieve current page by getCurrentScreen() (returns an integer) and one to set the page setCurrentScreen(int currentScreen, boolean animate)

So whenever I switch screens, the current page should still be selected, instead of creating the whole thing again and starting from page 1 (0 in the array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just slept over my question and solved it myself :)

What I did is:

I made a method called setPager(int pager) that sets my static in Pager to the current page.
This method is called from the HorizontalPager class whenever a screen is flipped.

Every time the screen flips, the onCreate() is called, and my HorizontalPager will be set to the value my static int has with a method setPager(int pager).

Answer (score 2):

Save the index of your page before a screen orientation change takes place:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return mIndex;//your index
}
```

In  onCreate():

```
Integer index= (Integer) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
```

If index is not null, then you have some data saved before the screen orientation changed, and should use it, otherwise ignore it.

Comment: If the answer was correct and helpful please mark the question as answered.